# How to catch-all a route and call a php function inside in a blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I working a in `Laravel` app, and I need to catch-all a route like: `https://localhost/myapp/someroute/` and this route call a controller that returning a view that contain a php scritp, and this php script need the rest of de  url (o route) for execute a function like:

```
function test()
{
    return round(microtime(true) * 1000);
}
```

For example, if I type: `https://localhost/myapp/someroute/test`, in the browser I should see the result of the function for that I need the `array_key_exists('PATH_INFO', $_SERVER)` exists in the script and call the function inside the php script I don't know if it's posible in Laravel.

With this code, I'm trying to catch-all the url:

```
Route::get('someroute/{function?}', function() {
   return view('directory.phpfilename');
})->where('function', '.*');;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this answer should work for you, I strongly suggest that you make sure that users can only call speciffic functions on your server. It could be a HUGE security risk to allow users to pass any php function name and get the response from the server.

I've added `$allowedFunctions` array for this, where you can specify which functions user can call.

Or you could create a class, where you can define the methods that users can execute, and then you would check given `$function` method exist in your class. If it does, execute function.

This is how you can run your function in the view

In your `routes/web.php`, add this

```
Route::get('/someroute/{function?}', function($function = null) {
  // check that parameter is passed and that function exists
  if ( empty($function) || ! function_exists($function) ) {
    return 'Function not found';
  }

  /*
    here you can list functions that user can call
    - don't allow users to run any function that's not on this list
  */
  $allowedFunctions = [
    'test',
  ];

  if ( ! in_array($function, $allowedFunctions) ) {
    return 'Function not allowed';
  }

  return view('directory.phpfilename', [
    'function' => $function,
  ]);
})->where('function', '.*');
```

In your view, to run the function use

```
{{ $function() }}
```

Or

```
{{ call_user_func($function) }}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, I think you could use the where method as well, ->where('function', 'test|function|function2') then remove the in_array check entirely

Comment: Although that is a good approach too, because the you give the client appropriate feedback when function is not allowed

Comment: @EdenReich that's also valid solution :)